# MySQL Table where each "data" have different amount informations

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

first sorry if the title is oddly written.
I need for a school project make a FlashCard game website and i need to store all my flashcards questions in the mysql database.
so i want to create a table which will contain all my flashcards like this :

```
"flashcard id"
"flashcard name"
"creator"
(and from now i will have different amount of questions)
"question 1:answer"
"question 2:answer"
"question 3:answer"
etc....
```

I'm using phpMyAdmin, and probably the latest versions of php and mysql.

Comment: You should have a 1:N table relationship there.

Comment: ok but.... how to do that ? I am a beginner on MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need at least two tables:
Table 1

```
CREATE TABLE flashcard 
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL, 
creator VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

In the second table I would store the questions and here is when The Impaler answer makes sense to me, 1:N is one to many relationship, so that for one flashcard there might be many (or several) questions associated. You create the 1:N with a foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE questions
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL, 
flashcard_id INT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT fk_flashcard1
    FOREIGN KEY (flashcard_id)
    REFERENCES flashcard (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

To collect your answer I would create a third table a foreign key which refers to questions.id

Please note I am also a beginner. 
For questions.name I selected VARCHAR (25) but it really depends on the string length

Comment: you forgot put a ```,``` after the ```flashcard_id INT NOT NULL```
But even if I fixed that, i can't create it because I receive this :
```#1075 - Only one automatic field is allowed and it must be indexed```
( I translated it from french )

Comment: Probably the PRIMARY KEY (id) of this table, between flaschcard_id  and constraint FK, sorry I forgot